# How to make groovy compiler to fail if method is not present?

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

I am doing a project in groovy using intellij. This is my first time with dynamic languages and it would be good if I could get compilation failures if:

- A method I am referring to is not present in the class
- A method is not returning proper return value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the point of dynamic language - methods could be added after compilation, at runtime

Btw, for methods on non-dynamic classes (maybe plain Java classes), you could try to annotate your code with `@CompileStatic`. At this case groovy compiler will link all calls at compile time, or fail if method doesn't exist.

See more docs about `@CompileStatic` and type checking: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_static_compilation

Comment: "Btw, for methods on non-dynamic classes (maybe plain Java classes)" - Just to be clear... dynamic methods can be added to Java classes at runtime the same way that they can be added to Groovy classes or any other class.

Comment: oh, yeah, thanks @JeffScottBrown. I meant java classes w/o added methods